# how to ignore self-signing certificate with NSURLRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlrequest

I need help with trying to bypass/ignor a self signing certificate.. I have looked everywhere and cannot find anything that has worked for me thus far..

I am trying to implements this [here](http://www.jasonhooker.com/content/2010-02-15/how-allow-self-signed-certificates-when-using-nsurlrequest-your-iphone-app)  however im not sure how to use this code

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(AllowAllCerts)

+ (BOOL) allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *) host {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

I add it to my app delegate but then I dont know what to do with it?

any help would be greatly appreciated..

currently I am not using anything because nothing has worked for me..

Comment: Use "Search" function before you post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got it to work.
I added these two methods just below the method where I call my connection to start.

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Comment: side note.. if you do this apple will not accept your code on submission. Hope this answers you question.

Comment: You might want to search your answer first before post one.

Comment: I had searched this, and tried it several times.. The actual code has two if statements in that second method.. I only later found that you had to remove the two if statements to get it to work.. :(

Comment: another alternative you might use `ASIHTTPRequest` class, and it is easy peasy... http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: I have been using ASIHTTPRequest libraries for the past year and decided to swap over after contacting ben (creator/maintainer) on the definitive verdict of the libaray. He told me to move on, as he said it wont be long till apple change something in their api's that will effect the way ASIHTTPRequest works.. (i.e. break it.)

Comment: agreed! its the most useful 3rd party library out there!