# Request to web service over SSL

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, nsmutableurlrequest

i am struggling to request web service using https. I am getting this kind of error:

```
An error occured : The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “SERVER_ADDRESS” which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

I am not using NSUrlConnectionDelegate. Here is my method:

```
- (void)sendRequestWithUrl:(NSURL*)url block:(void (^)(NSDictionary *dict, NSError *error)) block{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    NSError* err = nil;
    NSHTTPURLResponse* rsp = nil;
    // Perform the request synchronously on this thread
    NSData *rspData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&rsp error:&err];
    if (rspData && err == nil) {
        NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:rspData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&err];
        if(result) {
            block(result, err);
        } else {
            block(nil, err);
        }
    }else{
        DLog(@"Requesting URL: %@  An error occured : %@",url,[err localizedDescription]);
        block(nil, err);
    }
}
```

How i could solve this problem ?

Comment: Seems to me you are having problems with a self-signed certificate.. correct? 
I recommend you change to a lib such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/README.md) or [MKNetworking](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit/blob/master/README.mdown), which makes these kind of problems easier to handle. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077753/need-to-view-website-with-a-self-signed-certificate-and-http-authentication

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert

Comment: I don't want to use other libraries. Also in given other question solution is depricated

Comment: In that case, this might help: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/12/nsurlconnection-with-self-signed-certificates/

Comment: Also, this might help (1 year old post): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458989/how-to-ignore-self-signing-certificate-with-nsurlrequest. Its amazing what you can find, just by using google ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add below delegate methods to your communication class.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {
        if ([YOUR_HOST isEqualToString:challenge.protectionSpace.host])
        {
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];           
        }
    }   
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apple has a technote that covers this very well:

"Technical Note TN2232: HTTPS Server Trust Evaluation"

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2232/_index.html

Answer (score 2):

Well my solution was to create class `AsyncURLConnection` this code i found somewhere at http://stackoverflow.com but can't find it now. So i will give the code:

`AsyncURLConnection`:

**.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void (^completeBlock_t)(NSData *data);
typedef void (^errorBlock_t)(NSError *error);

@interface AsyncURLConnection : NSObject{
    NSMutableData *data_;
    completeBlock_t completeBlock_;
    errorBlock_t errorBlock_;
}

+ (id)request:(NSString *)requestUrl completeBlock:(completeBlock_t)completeBlock errorBlock:(errorBlock_t)errorBlock;
- (id)initWithRequest:(NSString *)requestUrl completeBlock:(completeBlock_t)completeBlock errorBlock:(errorBlock_t)errorBlock;
+ (id)requestWithMutable:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request completeBlock:(completeBlock_t)completeBlock errorBlock:(errorBlock_t)errorBlock;
- (id)initWithMutableRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request completeBlock:(completeBlock_t)completeBlock errorBlock:(errorBlock_t)errorBlock;
@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "AsyncURLConnection.h"

@implementation AsyncURLConnection

+ (id)requestWithMutable:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request completeBlock:(completeBlock_t)completeBlock errorBlock:(errorBlock_t)errorBlock
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithMutableRequest:request completeBlock:completeBlock errorBlock:errorBlock];
}

+ (id)request:(NSString*)requestUrl completeBlock:(completeBlock_t)completeBlock errorBlock:(errorBlock_t)errorBlock
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithRequest:requestUrl
                            completeBlock:completeBlock errorBlock:errorBlock];
}

- (id)initWithRequest:(NSString *)requestUrl completeBlock:(completeBlock_t)completeBlock errorBlock:(errorBlock_t)errorBlock
{
    if ((self=[super init])) {
        data_ = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        completeBlock_ = [completeBlock copy];
        errorBlock_ = [errorBlock copy];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestUrl];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithMutableRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request completeBlock:(completeBlock_t)completeBlock errorBlock:(errorBlock_t)errorBlock
{
    if ((self=[super init])) {
        data_ = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        completeBlock_ = [completeBlock copy];
        errorBlock_ = [errorBlock copy];
        [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [data_ setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [data_ appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    completeBlock_(data_);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    errorBlock_(error);
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0)
    {
        NSURLCredential *newCredential;
        newCredential=[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"someUser"
                                                 password:@"someUser"
                                              persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        DLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");

    }else{
        DLog(@"previous authentication failure");
    }
}
```

So in some controller this class could be used:

```
+ (void) downloadFileForURL:(NSURL *) url completionBlock:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSError *error)) block {
    NSString *requestURL = @"https://www.google.lt/restServer/Method";
    [AsyncURLConnection request:requestURL completeBlock:^(NSData *data) {
        /* success! */
        dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Download queue", NULL);
        dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
            /* process downloaded data in Concurrent Queue */
            if (data != nil) {
                block(data, nil);
            }else{
                block(nil,nil);
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                /* update UI on Main Thread */
            });
        });
    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        /* error! */
        block(nil,error);
    }];
}
```

Hope some one this code could help.

Thank you all for answers.

Answer (score 0):

This always happen for self-signed certificate. By using `NSURLConnectionDelegate`

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    if ([protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: How this code could be adjusted to mine ? I know how to do it with NSURLConnectionDelegate, but how to do it using blocks

Comment: why you don't want to use NSURLConnectionDelegate? Is there anything to break your code?

Comment: I would like to update my current code, because in other way i would need to make lot's of changes as now everything is done in blocks. Also i like writing code in this approach

Comment: Have a look at AFNetworking. It uses success- and failure-blocks and NSURLConnectionDelegate. If you can't use the framework directly, you will probably find the code to help you with your problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Trying this delegate method solved same issue for me.

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```